# How to enable generic microphone with an ALC 880 sound card?

Tags: 10.10, skype, microphone, google-talk

I have an external microphone plug in the back of my tower with a ALC 880 sound card. My sound for the speakers works great. But when I try to use my microphone in Google talk or Skype, no one can hear at the other end.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this:
 [image]

and/or [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/conversation/skype-fixing):  which may help.

Please inform of your results in order to edit/add this answer for a better solution.

Good luck!